# Array declaration difference verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

What is the difference in writing with this two methods?

Is there any significant difference?

```
logic array[32];
logic array[0:31];
```

Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. For unpacked array declarations, `[N]` is equivalent to `[0:N-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Technically there is not difference, but lower one looks more informative